# How to set case insensitive coupon codes in hybris?

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

Out Of The Box hybris promotion codes are case sensitive. If you creat a coupon code as TAKE50OFF, you need to enter it as TAKE50OFF to redeem, if you try Take50Off or take500ff, it will not work.

I know I can achieve this by converting entered code to all uppercase using javascript, but does hybris provide any configurable attribute to achieve this?

Comment: nope, there is no configuration attribute in the coupons service layer and data model etc. I would think your best bet is as you said to use custom code in the storefront to adjust the user input.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian